# Hitler's Death: Fact or Fiction

Tags: nazi-germany, hitler

Is there any consensus among modern day historians of how Hitler was killed or if he was killed, and is there any significant proof that he did die so as to disprove the conspiracy theorists?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because the death of Hitler was reported by the Soviets, this is generally the root cause of conspiracy theories.

The general consensus among historians is that Hitler committed suicide in his Führerbunker in Berlin, by gunshot on 30 April 1945, however, controversy will remain.

His body was found by a soviet counter-intelligence operations group called [SMERSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMERSH), this in itself is a cause of distrust for the first hand account.

This trust problem is furthered by disinformation from the Soviets, for example when President Truman asked Stalin at the Potsdam conference in August of 1945 if Hitler was dead, Stalin simply replied 'No'.

Over time, the story surrounding Hitler's fate was variously presented by the Soviets in line with their political motivations, in the years immediately following 1945, it maintained Hitler was not dead but had fled and was being shielded by former western allies.

At the time this worked, and it was stated at the Nuremberg trials that  "No one can say he is dead." (Thomas J. Dodd, chief of the U.S. trial counsel.)

The final account from the Soviets was that Hitler and Eva Braun, were buried at a SMERSH facility in Magdeburg, the exact location was kept a secret to avoid the site becoming a shrine for Neo-Nazis. It was also reported that the site, and the remains were destroyed.

This layering of misinformation, and the justifiable need for secrecy has left the ultimate fate of Hitler a mystery, which will never be truly solved.

Comment: Slomojo thanks for the answer  now it seems I have more questions then answers but thanks for the feedback

Comment: This is the nature of mysteries during warfare, when your enemy tells you something happened, it's generally greeted with skeptisim. When that enemy also distrusts itself intently, as was the case with Stalin's regime, you can see that the truth may well never surface. Of course, conspiracy theories will swarm around such events, but without conclusive proof, you are left with mystery and controversy, and sadly you can go no further.

Comment: @Slomojo: Do you have any sources to point us to? The [Wikipedia article on this topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler#Defeat_and_death) doesn't seem to leave much room for speculation and lists quite a few sources, both German and Soviet, that leave no doubt about the fact that Hitler indeed committed suicide.

Comment: If we are to trust KGB records, then we can accept the details of these sources. My point is that the extreme levels of deception at play during the Cold War make it quite difficult to be completely certain. Personally, I'm quite happy to accept that Hitler did indeed commit suicide, and the KGB records are *probably* truthful.  However, I think it is a matter of personal choice, as opposed to rock hard evidence, which unless you trust the KGB 100%, doesn't exist. I think rather than use the loaded term **mystery**, a better choice of words would be **the complete truth is unclear**.

Comment: @Slomojo: What does KGB have to do with that? Hitler wasn't alone when he committed suicide, several Germans saw his body and confirmed it afterwards. Soviets only found and identified that body several days later. SMERSH didn't appear in the story until much later - they didn't find him, they merely dug out the body after it was buried again.

Comment: I was under the impression that SMERSH was given the assignment of finding Adolf Hitler. I'd need to check my sources properly. Are you able to cite yours please?  With regards to the other witnesses, I'm not sure I could say I have no doubts about their credibility.  If Hitler actually did disappear (I'm not asserting this by the way.) do you really think his aides would give him up?  Either way, please try not to infer assertions in my questioning, I'm simply saying there is reason to doubt. Not that I have any beliefs about possible alternative stories or outcomes.

Comment: Let me put it another way, SMERSH, charged with, and successful (at least according to several authors) in finding Hitler, was a group composed of some very nasty characters, torturers and killers all, are providing one side of the story, and the other witnesses are in Hitlers entourage.  To me this is a bit of a problem with witness credibility.

Comment: @Slomojo: Since these groups have very different goals and their stories corroborate each other, it rather strengthens it. It would only be a problem with witness credibility of you assume some sort of Nazi-KGB conspiracy, which I find patently absurd, especially since the only goal of such a conspiracy would be to fake Hitlers death. And what use would that be today? None. Unless of course, there is a secret Nazi Army with Nazi UFO's at the south pole, or something, preparing to take over the world. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro That's certainly a good argument, however since both groups also have independent motivations for obfuscating the events, it's still not what I would call water tight. However, much of history is about making "best assumptions" and on that level I support the accepted story, if you want 100% certainty of course, you need to avoid history.

Comment: What is that source that Stalin said Hitler was alive?

Comment: @Anixx - I've had trouble digging up a source further than wikipedia, it requires further verification as to whether it's hearsay or fact.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because of the claim about Stalin lying Truman. This seems very unlikely to me.

Comment: Of course, today we know the secret Nazi army is at the dark side of the moon.

Comment: @Anixx: That seems very *likely*. Stalin lied a lot and murdered a lot of people. It would be almost surprising if he told the *truth*. I downvoted it because it says "has left the ultimate fate of Hitler a mystery, which will never be truly solved", which is incorrect. It is solved since a long time.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I hope it is clear from my answer and subsequent comments that when I say the *ultimate fate* I am referring to the entire details and timeline. Similarly, it should also be clear why I even use the word mystery. All the first hand sources have high motive to lie.  As I said before, I have little doubt that Hitler is dead / shot-himself etc. in line with the accepted story. However, if we are to place the burden of absolutes on these events, there is plenty to suggest we cannot possibly be 100% certain of anything. Not that this keeps me up at night, of course. ;)

Comment: Oh if Stalin never said truth then why they talked to him? Lol, this is just ridiculous. It is claimed that he lied without any supporting evidence and you believe it just because "he was a bad man, so he is likely to lie".

Comment: Well I researched the topic and it seems the claim that Stalin lied to Truman is by Bezymensky who promotes this idea under a brand name "big lie". He notes however that this reply by Stalin is absent from the Soviet recording of the conversation. The conversation was 17 July, but it is known that a day before Churchill and Truman visited the Hitler's bunker where they were told the Soviet version about how Hitler commited suicide.

Comment: @Anixx: Nobodu said he *never* said the truth. But he would of course lie as soon as he suspected that it was beneficial for him. He was at this point not prepared to admit that the Soviets had found Hitlers body, so he lied. Maybe he wasn't sure it was Hitler himself. So what? If you think that's unlikely, you need to read more Soviet history.

Comment: Lennart Regebro, the myth that Stalin deliberately lied about Hitler's death is debunked here: http://vlasti.net/news/85868 As I wrote before it was invented by Bezymensky. 16 July both Churchill and Truman were exposed to the Soviet version of the details of Hitler's suicide. Also as early as 26 May (when he himself knew no details) Stalin said Hopkins that there are claims that Hitler commited suicide and that the medics say they found the body of Goebbels with his kids, but he, hemself, does not believe in that. So he explained the version of suicide even when he did not know for sure yet.

Comment: Well I appreciate that you know Soviet history better than me who was born and still live in Moscow.

Comment: @Anixx: It's good that you appreciate that. Also note that I don't know if he lied or not, I'm arguing against your absurd claim that is is unlikely. No, it is very *likely*. And if you don't believe that, then you know very little about Stalin and Soviet history. The end.

Comment: Well in this case my feeling proved to be closer to the facts than yours.

Comment: @Anixx: It's also good that you admit that you based something on "a feeling". I didn't.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro So you *know* that Stalin lied in this case?

Comment: @Anixx: You seem to have trouble understanding what we are discussing. I can explain in chat if you like.

Comment: A new independent witness account has come to light, adding more confirmation to the "standard" events that Hitler committed suicide and that his body was burned outside the bunker. See update to my answer.

Comment: I saw this, it's good to get better clarification.

Comment: Hitler's death is dealt with by the British historian Hugh Trevor-Roper in  *The Last Days of Hitler*. HTR discovered that upon finding a body which appeared to be Hitler's the Soviet Commander on the spot immediately sought confirmation from Hitler's dentist. Dental records matched precisely. However when the officer wired Moscow saying they had Hitler, a message came back from the Kremlin - 'No you haven't, Hitler is still alive'. The Soviets continued to pedal this myth well into the 1950s.  Hitler was 'kept alive' for political purposes.

Answer (score 33):

There is some controversy of what happened to Hitler's remains, owing to the general disarray of war, but there is no real controversy with regards to his death.

Hitler did in his personal will and testament say that he had chosen death.

> I myself and my wife — in order to escape the disgrace of deposition
>   or capitulation — choose death. It is our wish to be burnt immediately
>   on the spot where I have carried out the greatest part of my daily
>   work in the course of a twelve years' service to my people.

Sources [1](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/My_Private_Will_and_Testament) [2](http://www.ns-archiv.de/personen/hitler/testament/faksimile/)

This is consistent with the eyewitness accounts of those who survived, like Hitler's secretary, [Traudl Junge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traudl_Junge), and [Rochus Misch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rochus_Misch). As such there is little doubt about the general events, although the exact details may be unclear.

Update: It has [recently come to light](http://www.bokus.com/bok/9789186597757/hitlers-svenska-ss-soldater-brev-och-dagbocker/) that a Swedish SS-officer was in the bunker, witnessed Hitler's wedding and saw Hitler's burnt body. He recounted this for the priest at the Swedish delegation in Berlin, who gave this information to the Swedish military, but did not confirm who the officer was until after that officers death. This description of the events also is consistent with other eyewitness accounts, and as this has been classified in the Swedish archives since 1945 it is a witness account that is independent from the other sources, significantly strengthening them.

Comment: Pertinent https://www.theguardian.com/world/2009/sep/27/adolf-hitler-suicide-skull-fragment

Comment: Yeah, the skull fragment found in 1946 was not Hitlers. This is quote uncontroversial.